# In Java can I create a data member which assumes a constant value on a per object basis

Tags: java

I want to create a java class with a data member say  `id` such that each object has its own `id` but the object id is assigned during object creation and then it can not be modified later.

Comment: Make it final and initialize once in constructor.

Comment: Use final, which can be assigned in constructor.

Comment: Is the fact that each object must have a *different* `id` part of the problem?

Comment: it should be a final attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Test {
  private final int id;

  public Test(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

A as final declared variable can only be initialized one time. At definition or at constructor.

Comment: I think without setter your id will not be changed as only way to supply it is *constructor* :)

Comment: @TAsk That's the point